# Database calls, 484ms apart, are producing incorrect results in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, aws-iot

We have "things" sending data to AWS IoT.  A rule forwards the payloads to a Lambda which is responsible for inserting or updating the data into Postgres (AWS RDS).  The Lambda is written in python and uses [PG8000](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000) for interacting with the db. The lambda event looks like this:

```
{
  "event_uuid": "8cd0b9b1-be93-49f8-1234-af4381052672",
  "date": "2021-07-08T16:09:25.138809Z",
  "serial_number": "a1b2c3",
  "temp": "34"
}
```

Before inserting the data into Postgres, a query is run on the table to look for any existing event_uuids which are required to be unique. For a specific reason, there is no UNIQUE constraint on the event_uuid column.  If the event_uuid does not exist, the data is inserted.  If the event_uuid does exist, the data is updated.  This all works great, except for the following case.

**THE ISSUE**: one of our things is sending two of the same payloads in very quick succession. It's an issue with one of our things but it's not something we can resolve at the moment and we need to account for it. Here are the timestamps from CloudWatch of when each payload was received:

- 2021-07-08T12:10:09.288-04:00
- 2021-07-08T12:10:09.772-04:00

As a result of the payloads being received 484ms apart, the Lambda is inserting both payloads instead of inserting the first and performing an update with the second one.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Here is part of the Lambda code...

```
conn = make_conn() 

event_query = f"""
  SELECT json_build_object('uuid', uuid)
  FROM samples 
  WHERE event_uuid='{event_uuid}'
  AND serial_number='{serial_number}'
"""

event_resp = fetch_one(conn, event_query)

if event_resp:

   update_sample_query = f"""
     UPDATE samples SET temp={temp} WHERE uuid='{event_resp["uuid"]}'    
   """

else:

   insert_sample_query = f"""
      INSERT INTO samples (uuid, event_uuid, temp)
      VALUES ('{uuid4()}', '{event_uuid}', {temp})
   """
```

Comment: Why is it sending the same payload? Is it truly sending the same data instance twice, or does it calculate the same data twice and send each once?  To get around this potential issue, I used a double guid/uuid value. The first was a machine random and the second was time-based. Depending on what uuid generator you're using (e.g., node has a package with 5 variations, I believe), you could very easily be generating the same uuid. Another option could be to generate the uuid in the database.

Comment: Also, postgres has an `insert ... on conflict x` where x is the action to take (including no action), but that would require a unique constraint on the column.

Comment: The "select and insert" (i.e. double check locking) is super inefficient and could be a source of bugs.  What if one Lambda queries and then a different Lambda inserts?  Your first Lambda thinks it's ok and then it inserts.  You're likely wasting nearly all of the reads as the odds are that the UUID doesn't exist.  Enable a unique constraint on the DB and handle a referential integrity constraint violation in your code.

Comment: What is the Python code in the Lambda actually doing? Add as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I added a snippet from my lambda.

Comment: @ps2goat - yes, it is truly sending the same data instance twice.  It's an edge case and, unfortunately, the software on the thing can't be fixed at the moment.  Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @stdunbar ... sounds like I'll be adding a unique constraint to the event_uuid column.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: So this `if event_resp:` is happening before the second record appears. Yeah,  pretty sure I see a unique constraint in your future. The other option is to spool the incoming data into a holding table and the periodically transfer distinct records to the final table.